# How do Advaitins counter the rebuttal of Ramanujacharya on Advaita Vedanta in His commentary on Bhagavad Gita 2.12?

Tags: bhagavad-gita, brahman, advaita, ramanujacharya, jiva

Shree Krishna in the Bhagavad Gita 2.12 states:

> "There  never  was  a  time  when  **I  did  not  exist,  nor  you,  nor  any  of  these  temporal  kings.  Nor  will there be any time in future when all of us shall cease to be.**"

And the following is the commentary of Ramanujacharya on this verse:

> “I,  [Krishna]  who  am,  as  you  know,  the  eternal  Lord  of  all,  was  never  non-existent,  but have  always  existed.  There  never  was  a  time  when  these  Selves  (jīvas)  like  you  [and  the others],  who  are  subject  to  My  sovereignty,  did  not  exist.  You  have  always  existed,  and 'all  of  us'  —   I  and  you,  shall  never  cease  to  be  'in  the  future';  we  shall  always  exist.   Just as  there  is  certainly    no  doubt  that  I,  the  Supreme  Self  and  Lord  of  all,  am  eternal, likewise,  you  [and  all  others]  who  are  embodied  Jīvas,  should  never  doubt  your  eternality either.” The  foregoing  teaching  implies  that  the  difference  between  the  Lord  who  is  the  sovereign over  all,  and  the  individual  jīvas;  as  also  the  differences  among  the  individual  jīvas themselves,  are  real.  This  has  been  declared  by  the  Lord  Himself  because  different  terms like  'I',  'you',  'these',  'all'  and  'we'  have  been  used  by  the  Lord  while  explaining  the  truth  of eternality  in  order  to  remove  the  misunderstanding  of  Arjuna  who  is  deluded  by ignorance.  As  regards  the  doctrine  of  Bhaskara  [and  the  Advaitins]  that  the  above  mentioned  distinctions [between  the  Lord  and  jīvas,  and  between  the  jīvas  themselves]    are  unreal  and  due  to  some limiting  condition  (Māyā)    —  it  would  be  highly  improper  [for  the  Lord]  to  make  reference  to distinctions  at the time of imparting  the [ultimate] Truth. If  we  examine  [Bhaskara's]  theory  of  upādhi  (adventitious  limitation),  which  states  that  the apparent    differences  among  jīvas  are  due  only  to  the  bodies  (adventitious  limitations),  it  must  be admitted  that  discussion  of  differences  is  out  of  place  when  explaining  the  ultimate  Truth,  because according to the theory  [of Bhaskara and the Advaitins] there are no such differences in reality.   The inherent differences mentioned by the Lord are taught by the Veda also:—  'Eternal  among  eternals, the  intelligent  among  the  intelligent, the  one  among  many  who  fulfils   desires’  (Sve.  Up.  6:13,  Ka.  Up.  2:2:13).     The  meaning  of  this  text  is:  —    ‘Among  the  eternal  sentient  beings  who  are  countless,  He,  who  is the Supreme Spirit fulfils the desires of all.'   **As  regards  the  doctrine  of  the  Advaitins  that  the  perception  of  difference  arises  from  ignorance (ajñāna  or  avidya)  only,  and  is  not  actually  real;    [it  may  be  pointed  out  that]  the  Supreme  Being — whose  comprehension  must  be  perfect,  free  from  all  ignorance  and  its  effects  —must  therefore have  a  direct  cognition  of  the  true  nature  of  the  ātman;  comprised  of  eternal  consciousness,  and being  without  any  differentiation  and    unchangeable.  He  therefore  cannot  possibly  be  aware  of  the so-called    differences  which  arise  from  ignorance.  It  is,  therefore,  unimaginable  that  He  would then  engage  Himself  in  activities  such  as  teaching  which  are  based  entirely  upon  such  a  perception of differences arising from  ignorance.**   It  may  be  argued  that  the  Supreme  Being,  though  perfectly  aware  of  non-duality,    can  still  be  aware  of  such  difference  which  persists  even  after  sublation.  For  example  a  burnt  piece  of  cloth may  continue  to  look  like  a  cloth,  and  that  such  continued  [perception]  of  the  nullified  does  not cause  Him  bondage.    Such  a  proposition  is  invalidated  in  the  light  of  another  analogy  of  a  similar kind,  namely,  the  perception  of  the  mirage.  When  a  mirage  is  realised  to  be  what  it  is,  one  does not  then  persist  in  an  attempt  to  fetch  water  there  from.  In  the  same  way,  even  if  the  impression  of difference  persists  after  it  has  been  nullified  by  the    realisation  of  non-dualism,  it  cannot  impel  one to  activities  such  as  teaching;  for  the  person  to  whom  the  instruction  is  to  be  imparted  is discovered  to  be  unreal.  The  idea  is  that  just  as  the  discovery  of  the  non-existence  of  water  in  a mirage  brings  an  end  to  all  efforts  to  get  water  from  it,  **so  also  when  all  duality  is  negated  by enlightenment, no activity like teaching disciples etc., could take place.  Nor  is  it  acceptable  that  the  Supreme  Lord  was  at  one  time  ignorant  and  obtained  knowledge  of non-duality  through  the  Scriptures,  and  is  still  being  subject  to  the  continuation  of  the  suppressed experiences.** Such a contention contradicts the  Veda (Śruti) and the Smrti (Canon Law):  — 'He,  who  is  all-knowing  and  all  wise'  (Mun.Up.,  1.1.9);   His  supreme  power  is  indeed  revealed  as  varied  and  inherent,  and  consists  of    omniscience, omnipotence  and  action'  (Sve.  Up.  6.8);  'I  know, Arjuna, all  beings  of  the  past,  present  and  future  but  no  one  knows  Me,'  etc.  (Gita  7:26).     And  again,  **if  the  perception  of  difference  and  distinction  are  said  to  persist  even  after  the  non-dual Self      has  been  decisively  realised,  the  question  arises—  to  whom  will  the  Lord  and  the  succession of  teachers  of  the  tradition  (Guru  Parampara)    impart  the  knowledge  in  accordance  with  their realisation?  The  question  requires  an  answer.  The  realisation  of  non-duality    cannot  possibly    coexist with the perception of differences.** If  the  Advaitins  reply  using  the  Bimba-Pratibimba  (the  original  and  the  reflection)  argument  that teachers  give  instructions  to  their  own  reflections  in  the  form  of  disciples  such  as  Arjuna,  it  is absurd.    For,  no  sane  person  would  attempt  to  give    instructions  to  his  own  reflection  seen  in precious  stone,  the  blade  of  a  sword  or  a  mirror,  knowing,  as  he  does,  that  they  are  non-different from  himself!  **The  theory  of  the  persistence  of  the  sublated  is  thus  impossible  to  maintain,  because the  knowledge  of  the  non-dual  Self     is  supposed  to  destroy  the  very  ignorance  in  which differences external to the Self are alleged based.**   'The  persistence  of  the  sublated'    does  indeed  occur  in  cases  where  the  cause  is  the  result  of  some physical  defect  such  as  the  seeing  of    two  moons,  in  impaired  eyesight  known  as  double-vision (diplopia).  This  double  vision  cannot  be  nullified  by  the  right  understanding  that  there  is  only  one moon.  Even  though  the  perception  of  the  two  moons  may  continue,  it  is  rendered  inconsequential on  the  strength  of  strong  contrary  evidence.  For,  it  will  not  lead  to  any  activity  based  upon  a  real experience.    **But  in  the  present  context  [in  the  case  of  Sri  Krishna  teaching  Arjuna],  the  concept  of  difference — where  both  object  and  cause  are  admittedly  unreal  —  is  negated  by  the  knowledge  of  reality. So the 'persistence of the sublated'  is impossible.   Thus,  if  the  Supreme  Lord  and  the    succession  of    preceptors  (guru-parampara)  have  attained  the realisation  of  [a  non-dual]  reality,  their  perception  of  duality  [after  realisation]  and  activities  such as  teaching  proceeding  from  such  [non-dual]  realisation,  are  impossible.  If,  on  the  other  hand,  the perception  of  difference  persists  because  of  the  continuation  of  ignorance  and  its  causes,  then these  teachers  are  themselves  ignorant  of  the  Truth,  and  they  will  be  incapable  of  teaching  the Truth.   Moreover,  as  the  preceptor  has  attained  the  realisation  of  the  non-dual  ātman  and  thereby  overcome  the  ignorance  obscuring  Brahman  and  all  the  effects  of  such  ignorance,  there  is  no purpose  in  instructing  the  disciple.  If  it  be  argued  that  the  preceptor  and  his  teaching  are  just  in  the imagination  of  the  disciple,  the  disciple  and  his  knowledge  are  similarly  the  product  of  the imagination  of  the  preceptor,  and  as  such  the  ignorance  in  question  cannot  be  overcome.  If  it  is maintained  that  the  disciple's  knowledge,  even  though  imaginary,  overcomes  ignorance  etc., because  it  annuls  the  previous  state  of  non-enlightenment,  the  same  can  be  asserted  of  the preceptor's  knowledge.** The  futility  of  such  teachings  is obvious.  Enough  of  these  unsound doctrines which have all thus  been refuted!

How do Advaitins counter the above rebuttal by Ramanujacharya on Advaita Vedanta?

**Update**: Ramanujacharya also tries to refute Advaitic doctrine of absolute unity of the Jiva while commenting on Bhagavad Gita 5.16 (**But to those whose ignorance is destroyed by Self-realisation, their enlightenment is supreme 
and illumines like the sun**) where He says:

> In the case of the enlightened ones, their delusion is destroyed by
>   wisdom. This  enlightenment arises from [studying] the teachings about
>   the real nature of the ātman, and  is then realized by daily practice.
>   The purity of this wisdom is unsurpassed, and in the  case of those
>   Jīvas who regain the expansive consciousness that is natural to them,
>   it is  found to be unlimited and un-contracted and illumines
>   everything like the sun.
>
> **The essential plurality of the Jīvas in their
>   original state is expressly mentioned in connection with  the
>   enlightened or fully realized ones by the expression 'those' in the
>   above text. In the beginning  (Gita 2:12) it was said — “There never
>   was a time when I did not exist, nor you, nor any of these kings of
>   men. Nor  will there be any time in future when all of us shall cease
>   to be”  — this statement is clarified here. Moreover, this plurality
>   [of Jīvas] cannot be due to limiting  factors imposed on a single
>   universal ātman [as taught by the Advaitins]. For, as stated here,
>   there is  no residual trace of such limiting adjuncts (such as
>   ignorance) for those that are fully enlightened,  and yet still, they
>   are described [by Krishna] as a plurality. Here consciousness is
>   taught as an  attribute inseparable from the essential nature of the
>   Self, because a difference between the Self and  its consciousness is
>   indicated by the statement**, 'Knowledge, in their case illuminates like
>   the sun’.  By the illustration of the sun, the relationship of the
>   knower to its knowledge is likened to the  luminous object and its
>   luminosity. Therefore, it is appropriate to consider that one’s
>   consciousness contracts through Karma, in the condition of Samsāra
>   (transmigration) and expands in the stage of  Mokṣa (liberation).

Comment: He has given good arguments. But why he is using analogy?

Comment: Any philosopher before using analogy, should first establish one to one correspondence between reality & analogy. For eg, Advaitins while describing Brahman & MAya uses the word - 'Desert' being a Brahman & mirage being 'unreal world', but at the same time they say Brahman is not conceivable & transcendental, then why they are relating Brahman with the desert?? This whole practice of establishing analogy without establishing one to one correspondence is entirely absurd IMO.

Comment: The second chapter of the gita is very confusing. It is difficult to understand whether Krishna is talking of one Self or multiple selves. No wonder there are different interpretations.

Comment: @Mr.Sigma. Analogy is always one-sided (UpamA ekadeshi) according to the NyAya-shastra.One's face is like a tiger does not mean that he has to have a tail!!

Answer (score 6):

There are three ways to answer this question. First, from the standpoint of the Atman, we are all the Atman and we exist eternally.

Second, from the standpoint of the eternal Brahman, there is no time - time exists inside Maya alone. As such, every moment of time exists eternally within Brahman. As such you exist eternally. You are not aware of your eternal existence but from Brahman's standpoint you can think of time as a line, we are on the line and see ourselves moving along it always every point on the line a new moment of time. We are not aware of the line but only the point we are on. From Brahman's standpoint, He 'sees' the line in its completeness. He 'sees' ever moment always - eternally. The passage of time and your awareness of the passage are only within Maya. As such, you - meaning your body, exists eternally.

The third way you can answer this is the repetition of the world. After every destruction of the world, it is recreated as before. Brahma Sutras I.3.30 (Swami Vireswarananda translator) says:

> And because of the sameness of names and forms (in every fresh cycle) there is no contradiction (to the eternity of the Vedic words) even in the revolving of the world cycles, as is seen from the Sruti and the Smriti.

and Shankara's commentary on this verse says:

> ...This eternal existence of the world in gross and fine forms are brought out by the Sruti and Smriti texts. "As formerly the Lord ordered the sun and moon, heaven, earth, the sky" etc. (Rg-Veda 10.190.3).

Swami Vivekananda writes (*Complete Works*, V2, pp 229-31, *Jnana Yoga*, sub-heading *Immortality*, available here - http://www.advaitaashrama.org/cw/content.php)

> But the question of immortality is not yet settled. We have seen that everything in this universe is indestructible. There is nothing new; there will be nothing new. The same series of manifestations are presenting themselves alternately like a wheel, coming up and going down. All motion in this universe is in the form of waves, successively rising and falling. Systems after systems are coming out of fine forms, evolving themselves, and taking grosser forms, again melting down, as it were, and going back to the fine forms. Again they rise out of that, evolving for a certain period and slowly going back to the cause. So with all life. Each manifestation of life is coming up and then going back again. What goes down? The form. The form breaks to pieces, but it comes up again. In one sense bodies and forms even are eternal. How? Suppose we take a number of dice and throw them, and they fall in this ratio — 6 — 5 — 3 — 4. We take the dice up and throw them again and again; there must be a time when the same numbers will come again; the same combination must come. Now each particle, each atom, that is in this universe, I take for such a die, and these are being thrown out and combined again and again. All these forms before you are one combination. Here are the forms of a glass, a table, a pitcher of water, and so forth. This is one combination; in time, it will all break. But there must come a time when exactly the same combination comes again, when you will be here, and this form will be here, this subject will be talked, and this pitcher will be here. An infinite number of times this has been, and an infinite number of times this will be repeated. Thus far with the physical forms. What do we find? That even the combination of physical forms is eternally repeated.
>
> A most interesting conclusion that follows from this theory is the explanation of facts such as these: Some of you, perhaps, have seen a man who can read the past life of others and foretell the future. How is it possible for any one to see what the future will be, unless there is a regulated future? Effects of the past will recur in the future, and we see that it is so. You have seen the big Ferris Wheel* in Chicago. The wheel revolves, and the little rooms in the wheel are regularly coming one after another; one set of persons gets into these, and after they have gone round the circle, they get out, and a fresh batch of people gets in. Each one of these batches is like one of these manifestations, from the lowest animals to the highest man. Nature is like the chain of the Ferris Wheel, endless and infinite, and these little carriages are the bodies or forms in which fresh batches of souls are riding, going up higher and higher until they become perfect and come out of the wheel. But the wheel goes on. And so long as the bodies are in the wheel, it can be absolutely and mathematically foretold where they will go, but not so of the souls. Thus it is possible to read the past and the future of nature with precision. We see, then, that there is recurrence of the same material phenomena at certain periods, and that the same combinations have been taking place through eternity. But that is not the immortality of the soul. No force can die, no matter can be annihilated. What becomes of it? It goes on changing, backwards and forwards, until it returns to the source from which it came. There is no motion in a straight line. Everything moves in a circle; a straight line, infinitely produced, becomes a circle. If that is the case, there cannot be eternal degeneration for any soul. It cannot be. Everything must complete the circle, and come back to its source. What are you and I and all these souls? In our discussion of evolution and involution, we have seen that you and I must be part of the cosmic consciousness, cosmic life, cosmic mind, which got involved and we must complete the circle and go back to this cosmic intelligence which is God. This cosmic intelligence is what people call Lord, or God, or Christ, or Buddha, or Brahman, what the materialists perceive as force, and the agnostics as that infinite, inexpressible beyond; and we are all parts of that.

Answer (score 2):

Sri Sankara argues that the differences refer to bodies and not to the Self.

> Never, at any time, was I not; on the contrary, I certainly ever was.
>   Though My body originated and pershed in the past, in them all, like
>   space in pots and the like, I remained an eternal entity. This is the
>   idea. Similarly you were not non-existent; on the contrary, surely you
>   too existed. So also these rulers of men were not non-existent; they
>   too existed, to be sure. So too we all shall not cease to exist, but
>   continue to be in the future as well, after the disintegration of the
>   body. **The idea is that in all the three divisions of time we are
>   eternal as identical with the Self. The plural number in verse 12
>   refers to differences in respect of bodies; it does not point to a
>   plurality of Selves.**

Bhagavad Gita Basya of Sri Sankaracharya translated by A. G. Krishna Warrier

**Why would Lord Krishna talk about bodily notions in a lecture meant for moksha?**

A probable answer is that Lord Krishna is only at the start of his teaching and does not want to confuse Arjuna who is presumably ignorant of high philosophy. Arjuna is a representative of the common man and it is better to start with concepts that he is familiar with rather than proceed with higher conceptions at the very beginning. He will be gradually led to subtler and finer concepts as the lecture proceeds. This is how almost all teachings proceed.

Comment: Shankaracharya definitely says that difference is wrt bodies. But if you add why speaking of such a notion when imparting ultimate knowledge to Arjuna is justified on part of lord, then the answer would look more complete. The point of Ramanujacharya is thet God would not propose such a bodily notion nd that God is nt speaking from standpoint of maya bt from stanpoint of absolute.

Comment: Good point. I have discussed a probable reason why Lord Kirshna may have meant bodies.

Comment: This partially answers my question. Why is the perception of difference  existing in one who has realised the non-dual Self? Since Krishna is free from any kind of ignorance or avidya, He isn't supposed to find differences arising out of avidya.

Comment: @SuryaKantaBoseChowdhury maybe that's a flow of explanation, maybe Krishna's point of view was meant to educate Arjuna from a root point of Vedanta philosophy, because if you see....Arjuna was terrified to see Krishna in his absolute Vishwaroopa form and asked him to return to his original body. So Krishna might just have meant the physical shell. Either way both the philosophies are fluid and logical.

Comment: @ArkaprabhaMajumdar I got that but the question is why the perception of difference is arising in Krishna or any Advaitin Guru? If they have become Brahman after realising the "non-dual Self", they are supposed to see no differences between the unrealised and realised since they all are Brahman.

Comment: @SuryaKantaBoseChowdhury Krishna is speaking to a largely ignorant Arjuna in the middle of a battle field. Even if Krishna has experienced nonduality, there is no reason to believe Arjuna has experienced it. Thus Krishna is talking in dualistic language. There is no concept of a teacher and student in the nondual realm. Who will teach whom since there is no second entity? Thus it is reasonable to assume that Krishna is talking about bodies.

Comment: The Guru is not speaking from his perspective. He is speaking from the student's level from which he'll slowly elevate his pupil to the non-dual stage.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the only major Advaitin commentator on the Bhagavad-Gita to have responded to Ramanuja's rebuttal on this verse, is Bal Gangadhar Tilak:

> In commenting on this stanza, it is stated in the Ramanujabhasya that if both “I”, that is, the Supreme Being, and ‘You and these Kings’, that is, the other Atmans, existed in the past and will be born in the future ten, according to this stanza, the Supreme Being, and the Atman both become separate, independent, and permanent entities. **But, this argument is not correct, it is a partisan argument in support of a particular doctrine; because, this stanza is intended to explain only that both are permanent; and their mutual inter-relation is not stated here, nor was there any occasion for doing so.** When that occasion arose later on, we find stated in clear terms in the Gita Itself, the Non Dualistic (advaita) doctrine that the Paramesvara, that is, the Blessed Lord, is the embodied Atman in the bodies of al created beings.

Hence, according to the Advaita school, Krishna is only referring to the bodies here.